# Why won't this view load correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried pushing to my `ChatView` view controller from my `UserProfile` view controller in a number of different ways:

**UserProfile.m**

```
ChatView *chatView = [[ChatView alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chatView animated:YES];
```

Also:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
ChatView *chatView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chat_view"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chatView animated:YES];
```

And also I have tried modal presentations:

```
[self presentViewController:chatView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

These don't actually crash, but they all fail to get past this bit of `viewDidLoad`:

**JSQMessagesViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    NSLog(@"We see this log");

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([JSQMessagesViewController class])
                                  owner:self
                                options:nil];

    NSLog(@"We do not see this log");
    ...
}
```

**Additional info**
The above code all works *absolutely fine* when I push to this view from my `RecentChats` view controller. The key difference, I think, is that my `UserProfile` view controller itself loads nibs, whereas `RecentChats` is a more straightforward Storyboard-built `UITableViewController`, and I wonder if is the nib loading in `UserProfile` this is causing issues.

Comment: The name suggests that `ChatView` is a view not a View Controller. Is that true?

Comment: It is. `ChatView : JSQMessagesViewController : UIViewController` - it's a library I downloaded here: https://github.com/relatedcode/NotificationChat

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you are doing many fundamental things wrong and they are culminating in your code not working.

You should read Apple's View Controller Fundamentals.

To name a few problems, you are using the wrong initialize function for a View Controller. Unless a subclass designates otherwise, `-initWithNibNamed:bundle:`(typing from memory on my phone; sorry if I'm not exact) is the correct method.

Your view controller's main view is loaded in the `-loadView` method, not `-viewDidLoad`. If you are using a NIB, the name of the NIB should be passed into the initialize method, not loaded via `-loadNibNamed:`.

I could go on for a while, but you get the point.